# Travel advice back to UK from Jamaica after covid-19 outbreak

Tags: uk, covid-19, jamaica, tui

apologies for sloppy writing due to my current situation.
I am currently in Jamaica with TUI all inclusive holiday. Just an hour ago I got email from Gov.Uk Travel advice stating following.

> The Foreign and Commonwealth Office advise against all but essential travel to Jamaica due to restrictions imposed by the Jamaican authorities in response to the coronavirus (Covid-19) pandemic. **British nationals who wish to leave Jamaica are encouraged to make travel arrangements urgently before airlines reduce direct and indirect flight options**. (‘Summary’ and ‘Health’ page)
>
> Time updated
>   11:12pm, 14 March 2020

Reference https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/jamaica

Does this mean or is there an indirect signals that UK government would be closing borders for all affected countries soon?

I reached out to TUI asking specifically that whether TUI would be arranging immediate flight in case of sudden news from UK gov to close borders in short period of time? Their response was lengthy but in essence they said they will try their best to bring everyone home if such case occurs.

In addition I also got to know that outgoing flights from UK to Jamaica are suspended from 16th of March.

I myself and my partner are immigrant in UK and resident on Tier 2. Given the situation I am very confused on what should be my next move?

Should I arrange other flights immediately to return home or wait until next update?

Ps. I do have travel insurance, my scheduled flight is on 20th of March

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean or is there an indirect signals that UK government would be closing borders for all affected countries soon?

No, it means that due to **Jamaica's** restrictions there may be **less planes available** to return with.

> Their response was lengthy but in essence they said they will try their best to bring everyone home if such case occurs.

This is, for them, a **logistic** problem. Will the plane needed be there on the 20th for your scheduled return flight?.

Having a reservation relatively soon after the 16th is a positive point for you. Somebody who would be casually traveling from island to island less so.

Assume nobody is interested in keeping peaple stranded. It may not work out *exactly* as planned, but as seen in the recent past, everybody was able to return.

Keep in close contact with your travel agent and make sure you are available at short notice to leave.

If you are not satisfied with this arraignment, you can make your own. But assume this may be difficult.

Also make sure that your **travel insurance** covers this situation if you expect them to cover the costs of your private arrangements.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I am safely back home and currently self Isolating. You were right about logistics issue, but they did manage it by setting up flight that came to near by islands / Mexico, though they were running low on flight services such as food, drinks and blankets for travellers and flight attendants seemed exhausted.